# Importing android recyclerview using eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-recyclerview

Ive been fighting this all day, how do i import (properly) the recyclerview using eclipse into a project, i've tried using both only the jars and trying to import the whole library, i even opened a new project just to make sure i dont have any conflicting stuff happening please help :/

here is everything i can provide regarding my project, i simply opened a new one, imported the jar file from the recyclerview in the support library and added a view to the xml, nothing else. still gets broken.

[image: project structure]

[image: logcat 1/3]

[image: logcat 2/3]

[image: logcat 3/3]

[image]

Comment: You need to add the files from the res folder also to your path because RecyclerView needs them

Comment: I will try but im skeptical since importing the entire library gave the same result